# Find an easy web server framework for mobile game

Tags: javascript, php, android, web-services

I need a web server to provide api interface like login/ranking for a mobile game, which web framework should I use, I primary program C++ before.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better asked over at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try out Firebase (https://www.firebase.com/) if you're looking for something relatively easy to store game data with. If you're looking for something to manage logins and storing simple data, either Twitter's Fabric (https://get.fabric.io/) and AWS Cognito (https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/) can also be used as well

Comment: link only answers are discouraged

Comment: @matthew-merryfull A possible answer with how to setup Fabric Digits with Firebase shall be very helpful.